# Как импортировать базу innoDB (хотя бы в общих чертах) - ошибка 1146

Tags: mysql, innodb

Критически важно! Спасите!
Как перенести базу данных innoDB с одного компьютера на другой?
Экспортировал файл с помощью Server -> Data Export. Получился 1 sql-файл, но при импорте на другой компьютер (Server -> Data Import) возникает ошибка 1146 (talbe doesn't exist).
[Нашел этот материал](https://bobcares.com/blog/1146-table-doesnt-exist/)

Там сказано о каких-то файлах ibdata и .frm, но где их достать? 
Помогите! Завтра БД надо преподу показать!

Вот, как я экспортировал базу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Advanced options не менял.

Если экспортировать без Include Create Schema, то возникнет ошибка 1142: SELECT, LOCK TABLES command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'accounts'

Если импортировать одну структуру - возникнет ошибка 1022: no database selected.

Comment: Через бэкап на старом сервере и ресторе на новом. Другие методы сложнее и требуют определённых знаний и квалификации. П.С. InnoDB бывают таблицы, а не БД.

Comment: @Akina, а как это сделать? Какие опции в Workbench жать? Добрый вечер, кстати!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17190083 какой из вариантов вы выбрали при экспорте базы?

Comment: @KostaB. первый.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам надо перенести информацию из таблиц, могу предложить `mysqldump`

Для получения таблицы:

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p DATABASE table > table.sql
```

На другом компьютере:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE < table.sql
```

Comment: Желательно и таблицы, и информацию.
Программа открывается и тут же закрывается. И чем она отличается от Data Export в Workbench?

Comment: Она и таблицы и информацию берет. Команда делает дамп таблицы. Дамп будет содержать набор команд SQL для создания и заполнения таблиц.

Comment: получилось стандартным способом (Server -> Data Import) перенести структуру с процедурами. Данные пришлось вписывать самому. Ну и на том спасибо!